# How to bind event handlers using Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control

How do you bind event handlers with dependencies using Ninject and scope them to the class they are attached to such that when that class goes out of scope the event handler can be removed and it's dependency disposed?

Lets say I have a class with event handler

```
class Foo
{
    public EventHandler EventHappened;
}
```

and a class that will act as a notifier of the event

```
class Bar
{
    public void Notify(object sender, EventArgs args) { //some work }
}
```

How does one attach Bar to Foo using Ninject such that if Bar has a disposable dependency

```
class Baz : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { }
}

class Bar
{
    Baz baz { get; private set;}

    public Bar(Baz baz) { this.baz = baz; }
}
```

that when Foo goes out of scope, Baz.Dispose() is called too?

I was binding everything like so

```
Bar notifier = null;
Bind<Baz>().ToSelf().WhenInjectedInto<Bar>().InParentScope();   
Bind<Bar>().ToSelf().InParentScope(); 
Bind<Foo>()
    .ToSelf()
    .InSomeScope()
    .OnActivation((context, instance) =>
    {
         notifier = context.Kernel.Get<Bar>();
         instance.EventHappened += notifier.Notify;
    })
    .OnDeactivation((context, instance) =>
    {
         instance.EventHappened -= notifier.Notify;
         context.Kernel.Release(notifier);
    });
```

but I don't think the variable containing Bar is scoped like the others and does not truly get disposed. Also binding it this way, there is no clear way to tell the next programmer that the event handler needs to be scoped this way or else it wont get disposed with out putting a novel's worth of comments around it. Is there a better way of binding classes in this configuration using Ninject?

Thanks in advance.